# Differentiate different firebase first_open attribution

Tags: firebase

I have firebase integrated. And currently I have a few hundreds of "first_open" in attribution.

However, currently, they are all (direct).

Is there a way for me to call in my code so that i could differentiate between different ways of first_open?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can add parameters to `first_open` event. But what you can set a custom event for your specific case, and you can also add some parameters to it.

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(CUSTOM_EVENT) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, id)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
    param(CUSTOM_PARAM, text)
}
```

You can read the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android#kotlin%20ktx) for more information.